# Duplicated django ORM query n+1

Tags: python, django

I have a models looks like this

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
   income_period_choices = (("Weekly", "Weekly"), ("Fortnightly", "Fortnightly"))
   chp_reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
   rent_effective_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

class FamilyGroup(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=name_choices)
   transaction = models.ForeignKey(
       Transaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="family_groups"
   )
   family_type = models.ForeignKey(
       FamilySituation, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True
   )
   last_rent = models.DecimalField(
       help_text="per week", max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True
   )
    @property
    def rent_assessment_rate(self):
        return RentAssessmentRate.objects.get(active="Yes") # here i think i should add select_related maybe or something, but im not sure

    @property
    def ftb_rate(self):
        return self.rent_assessment_rate.ftb

    @property
    def cra_rate(self):
        return self.rent_assessment_rate.cra

    @property
    def maintenance_rate(self):
        return self.rent_assessment_rate.maintenance
```

views

```
def index(request):
    transaction = Transaction.objects.all().prefetch_related('family_groups')

    return render(request, 'cra/index.html', {"transaction":transaction})
```

So I'm getting a duplicated queries from `RentAssessmentRate` table while trying to retrieve the data on the FamilyGroup table.

[image]

What would be a good approach to avoid such duplicates? Thanks in advance

Comment: The `rent_assessment_rate` makes not much sense, since apparently it will look for the *all* objects to the `RentAssessmentRate` for one that is active, but that is not specific to a `FamilyGroup`, etc.

Comment: Sould i add a foreign key RentAssesmentRate to FamilyGroup, you mean?